# Problems with a background image to create a shadow in a CSS layout

Tags: html, css, layout, xhtml, themes

I am studying on a tutorial how create a fixed tabless CSS layout starting from Photoshop to HTML+CSS code.

This is the final example proposed bu the tutorial (how it have to look like at the end):

http://www.html.it/articoli/1688/template/11-css.html

and this is my personal version of the previous template: http://onofri.org/example/WebTemplate/

How can you see I have some problem in Firefox with the left shadow of the left column (with others browser I have others problems)

As in the example template I have create this shadow by setting the bgpage.gif immage as background of the #container div and putting it on the right of this div:

```
#container {
    /* consente di posizionare un elemento al centro del suo contenitore (non tutti i browser la supportano) */
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 770px;   /* Imposto la larghezza */
    background: url(../images/bgpage.gif) repeat-y scroll 103% 0 transparent;
}
```

Why in the example proposed by the tutorial work well and in mine don't work?

Someone can help me to solve?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I think you're referring to how the shadow between the sidebar and the left content isn't appearing.

The reason your `#container` element isn't creating the shadow, despite having it as a repeating background, is because that element doesn't go any lower than the `#header` element. Since almost all of the elements within `#container` are floated, their heights don't cause the parent to expand, so its background doesn't show there.

To fix this, you would need to use the `clear` CSS property - which the tutorial example implements through the styling of the `#clearer` element.

So, add to your CSS:

```
#clearer{
    clear:both;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

...which is exactly what the tutorial example uses, and you should see some improvement. (Though this does reveal a couple other issues - namely, in how your image assets conflict with each other a bit.)

If this isn't what you were looking for, feel free to let me know, and I'll be happy to help you further. Good luck!